# hash with strange string in redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've started to explore redux, in this [repo](https://github.com/GoThinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app) here's the demo: https://react-redux.realworld.io/#/?_k=m641rd

why there's a # followed by strange string when i navigate around the app? I can't find way to remove them in the codes.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url

Comment: @CD.. I've read that but I don't get it, that's why I ask here. I've seen react app with no hash able to use html's history.

Answer (score 0):

The # followed by strange string when you navigate around the app is not caused by redux. It is caused because your app uses react-router. The router uses the information contained in the string to render the correct components for the particular page that is requested.

You can setup react-router to create real URLs that look like example.com/some/path, but then you will also need some configuration on the server.

For a quick sample, it's better to setup react-router to use 'hash history'. Hash history works without configuring your server, but it has these strange looking # strings as a disadvantage.

[Here is some info](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md) on the difference between browser history (nice looking url's) and hash history (# sign in the url)

You can notice hash history is being used in your sample app when you look at the following line, inside `index.js`:

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
```

You can replace that line with

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
```

but it will only work if you also change the server configuration. You don't write what server you are using. There are some examples (nginx, apache) [in the documentation.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)

Comment: some configuration is just one line of code on the server, strange string looks real ugly